# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-11: illegal encoding

Tags: db2, pyodbc

I am getting

```
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-11: illegal encoding
```

and sometime

```
 curr.execute(sql)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 4: unexpected end of data
```

connecting to
DB2 database using `iAccess Client Solutions` driver

- python 3.6
- pyodbc 4.0.30

got a valid connection object, so connection is successful, however parsing the SQL string is having problem, not sure why pyodbc is not passing the SQL string to the driver, do not have any special character/non unicode character in the SQL.

Also, the same code works fine in python3.4/pyodbc 3.0.7 with same Db2 iAccess driver version.

When captured `mtrace` output it shows below where after `curr execute` call `codecs.utf_16_le_decode` gets called, not sure why. Is this default behavior in python 3.6?

```
test_as400_36.py(41): curr.execute(sql)
 --- modulename: utf_16_le, funcname: decode
utf_16_le.py(16):     return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(77):         sys.settrace(None)

 
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x7f3b3e8068a0>
```

below the code.

```
import sys
import pyodbc
import csv
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level='INFO', format='[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s] %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

pyodbc.pooling = False
print("pyodbc version " + pyodbc.version)

cnxn=pyodbc.connect(r'DSN={};UID={};PWD={};'.format("DSN1","User1","passwd"))

print(cnxn)

curr=cnxn.cursor()

sql='''select
FXLCCN
from AILLIB.annpymtK
'''

curr.execute(sql)


arraysize=500000
logging.get_logger()
rows_fetched=0

while True:
            results = curr.fetchmany(arraysize)
            cnt_rows_fetched = len(results)
            logger.debug('%s Rows Fetched', cnt_rows_fetched)
            rows_fetched += cnt_rows_fetched
            logger.info('%s Total Rows Fetched', rows_fetched)
            if not results:
                curr.close()
                break
```

Comment: Can you do a simple `select 1 as FXLCCN`. (I don't know if DB2 supports SELECT without FROM.)

Comment: Suggest you chase this via github pyodbc issues page, https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues  , as others have reported this, and found in some cases workarounds.

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/755